# Docker imagebuild for Postgresql initializing materialized view

Tags: postgresql, docker, materialized-views

I face weird problem I'd like to understand with respect to postgres initialization at docker image build. My base image is

```
FROM bitnami/postgresql:14.5.0
```

Where I mount a custom SQL init script into, executed at `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` according to documentation. The script is perfectly executed for creating tables, importing data and so on.

The very last statement is the creation of a materialized view. As soon as the build process comes to that statement, the entire docker build stuck. It does not exit with an error but does not continue at all, while CPU stays constantly at 10-15% in average. I waited for an hour before I was cancelling the build process.

When I do the same with no data (i.e, defining the MV but not initializing it) the docker build passes and finishes with no error.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW myViewName AS
<Large SQL statement omitted for better readability>
WITH NO DATA;
```

Running the image as container, connection to PostgreSQL and performing the MV refresh like

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW myViewName;
```

takes ~30 seconds for 2M rows.

So why does this fail during build when perfectly working inside a container? Does anybody faced a similiar behaviour and may point me to the right direction?